# Code not running on RPI Pico

Tags: pi-pico

I have the following code on the RPi Pico W:

```
include "pico/stdlib.h"

#define LED 25

int main()
{
    gpio_init(LED);
    gpio_set_dir(LED, GPIO_OUT);
    while (true)
    {
        gpio_put(LED, 1);
        sleep_ms(250);
        gpio_put(LED, 0);
        sleep_ms(250);
    }
}
```

I'm using `CMake` and `pico-sdk` to compile it, and the code compiles with no issues. When I put the code on the Pico the led doesn't blink, I tried changing the GPIO output to other pins and connecting them to an external LEDs, but it didn't work either.

Anyone has any Idea on how to fix it?

PS: I'm using an M1 macbook to compile.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation again. This is a Pico program NOT PicoW - the LED is accessed differently.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. I haven't tested this myself in C/C++ but have done so in MicroPython and TinyGo :)

The LED is no longer connected to pin 25 on the Pico W - so you have to access it 'indirectly' - this page gives details - https://www.electromaker.io/blog/article/getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi-pico-w-cc-sdk

Search for `CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN` to see the code - you will also need to follow preceding instructions to setup your tool chain.

For interest - here is a TinyGo blink - which compiles to a 17KB UF2 - which might interest you if you're looking for a compiled alternative to C...

```
package main

import (
    "machine"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    led := machine.LED
    led.Configure(machine.PinConfig{Mode: machine.PinOutput})

    for {
        led.Set(!led.Get()) // toggle LED

        time.Sleep(time.Second / 4)
    }
}
```